# best way to ruin motion blur with gometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, eevee-render-engine, motion-blur

this ones a weird one, i have noticed that some geometry nodes modifiers like realize instances tend to make the object motion blur disappear on some frames, but it's very inconsistent. surprisingly, this is actually what i want.
i want to render in eevee with motion blur only for camera motion, so camera movements feel smooth, but not the object motion (because i am using smear frames instead).
does anyone know a way to consistently ruin motion blur data for an object (character animation from alembic cache) with geometry nodes or other modifiers?
i could of course also render the animation a second time in cycles to get the motion vector pass, but i'd still have to find a way to kill object vector data for it